# How to remove a certain node in a single linked list and return this node?

Tags: c++, data-structures

In a single linked list, I want to get a certain node with the number `min` and then remove the node from list. The problem is that, if the number I want to remove reaches the head of the list, it will never be removed. I think the logic is correct, I don't know where I am wrong.

```cpp
struct Node *getMin(struct Node *head, int min){

    struct Node *pre = (struct Node *)malloc(sizeof(struct Node));
    pre->data = head->data;
    if (pre->data == min)
    {
     head = head->next;
     return pre;
    }
    else{
     struct Node *temp = head;
     struct Node *cur = temp->next;
     while(cur != NULL){
         if(cur->data == min){
             temp->next = cur->next;
             return cur;
         }else{
             temp = cur;
             cur = cur->next;
         }
     }
    }
    return head;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I don't know where I am wrong?

You'll have to stay one node ahead for all but the head node.

```
struct Node *cur = head;
while ( cur->next != NULL )
{
   if ( cur->next->data == min )
   {
      struct Node *temp = cur->next;
      cur->next = cur->next->next;

      // Now temp is orphaned and can be returned to the calling
      // function.
      return temp;
   }
   else
   {
      cur = cur->next;
   }
}

// Return NULL to the calling function indicating that
// the item was not found.
return NULL;
```

**PS**

Use of

```
struct Node *pre = (struct Node *)malloc(sizeof(struct Node));
```

does not seem right. When the item is at the head node, you use

```
head = head->next;
return pre;
```

which causes a memor leak. The previous value of `head` is lost to the program. The prgoram has no way of deallocating the dynamically allocated memory that it used to point to.

Here's an updated version of the entire function body.

```
if (head->data == min)
{
   struct Node *temp = head;
   head = head->next;

   // Now temp is orphaned and can be returned to the calling
   // function.
   retgurn temp;
}

struct Node *cur = head;
while ( cur->next != NULL )
{
   if ( cur->next->data == min )
   {
      struct Node *temp = cur->next;
      cur->next = cur->next->next;

      // Now temp is orphaned and can be returned to the calling
      // function.
      return temp;
   }
   else
   {
      cur = cur->next;
   }
}

// Return NULL to the calling function indicating that
// the item was not found.
return NULL;
```

**PS 2**

- If you are using C++, as your tag indicates, don't use `malloc` to allocate memory for a node. Use the `new` operator.
- There is no need to use `struct Node* cur` to declare a variable. Use `Node* cur`.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply! Your suggestions make my code much more readable. But the core problem is not what you suggest. It is because the parameter (*head) passed to the function is not my originally defined list, instead it is just a copy of the real list, therefore only changing the head in the function doesnt work. I made a new list with the head storing nothing and pass the new head to the function and finally works!!

Comment: It is really the matter of me getting used to the C++ parameter habits. Anyway, your reply is priceless.